# How can I resample an SVG?

Tags: svg

I'm not sure 'resample' is the right word, so what I want to do is change the natural height and width of an SVG. This would re-calculate all the points, but keep the exact same resultant image.

For example:

```
<svg width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
  <polygon points="0,0 10,10 30,30" />
</svg>
```

to:

```
<svg width="60px" height="60px" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
  <polygon points="0,0 20,20 60,60" />
</svg>
```

Comment: [This article](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/) will likely be very useful for you

Comment: What would be the point of doing that @DavidCook?

Comment: Good question @Robert, the reason is I found that Mobile Safari 5 (ie iPad 1st gen) wasn't rendering my .svg file correctly; and I perceived that if the natural size matched with the target size, I'd have a more compatible result.

Comment: And adjusting the width/height without changing the viewBox or contents doesn't help?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to easily test as I don't have access to an old iPad or iOS5 emulator :(. I have resolved the issue by forcing a png fallback for old versions of webkit, but if I get a chance to test width/height, I will report back.